# Pinterest style of text

Tags: php, text, upload, pinterest

I'm creating a news feed site. User can upload text and then it displays the texts below eachother. I want to display all the texts in a way that Pinterest displays pictures. How can I do this?

The code for displaying and getting the text from the database is:

```
<?php

//connect

mysql_connect("host","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

//query the database
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_query());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews))
{

    //get data
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $date = $row['date'];

    echo "
    <b>$title posted on $date</b><br>
    ";

    echo nl2br($body);

    echo "<hr>
    ";

}



?>
```

And the code for posting a text is like:

```
<?php


  //insert category to database
  if(isset($_POST['qty'])) {
    // Fetch and clean the <select> value.
    // The (int) makes sure the value is really a integer.
    $qty = (int)$_POST['qty'];


    // Create the INSERT query.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`quantity`)
            VALUES ({$qty})";

    // Connect to a database and execute the query.
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('database_name', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Check the results and print the appropriate message.
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}






     if ($_POST['post'])
{
    //get data
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    //check for existance
    if ($title&&$body)
    {
        mysql_connect("host","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        //insert data
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('','$title','$body','$date')") or die(mysql_error());

        die("Your text has been posted!");

    }
    else
        echo "Please fill out your name and text<p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: http://youngcreativity.se/news.php – there is the news feed. And http://youngcreativity.se/post.php – the post page.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But please help me fix my question? :)

Comment: So, what would you like to do exactly? The Title says "Pinterest style of text" but in the description it's "in a way that Pinterest displays pictures"? Do you want to display a **grid** with all posts "like Pinterest" does?

Comment: Yes, I want to display a grid with all posts "like Pinterest" does!